# Numerical Integration seems to give wrong result

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a long expression numerically. But I just noticed that something is off with the integration. I have to integrate from 1 to 0.1. When I integrate from 1 to 0.2 & 0.2 to 0.1 and add up, it gives a different result than just integrating from 1 to 0.1. Is it due to some problem in the method of integration? Which one is better in this case?

```
dofdata = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "gstar.txt", "Table"]; 
g = Interpolation[dofdata, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Hermite"];
ratedata = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rate.txt", "Table"];
Subscript[C, e] = 
  Interpolation[ratedata, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Hermite"];
f\[Nu]s = 
  Function[{r, sin2\[Theta], ms, Ti, Tf}, 
   Block[{GF = 1.166*10^-5, 
     MPl = 1.22* 10^19, \[Eta]B = 6.05*10^\[Minus]10, mZ = 91.1876, 
     mW = 80.379}, {$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000};
    NIntegrate[((-Sqrt[90/(8*Pi^3)]*MPl) /( 
         g[T]^(1/2)*T^3))*(1 + (T*g'[T])/(3*g[T]))*0.25*
      Subscript[C, e][T]*GF^2*
      (( r*T^6)/
        Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/
         3)  ((ms^2 * 
           sin2\[Theta])/(2*(( r*T^2)/Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3)))^2*
      ( ((ms^2 * 
              sin2\[Theta])/(2*(( r*T^2)/Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3)))^2 + 
         (Subscript[C, e][T]*GF^2*(( r*T^6)/Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))^2/
          4 + 
         (ms^2/(2*(( r*T^2)/Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3)) -
            ((2*\[Sqrt]2*1.20206*GF*\[Eta]B*T^3)/(4*Pi^2) -
              ((8 \[Sqrt]2 *GF)/(3*mZ^2))*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/
                  3)*2*((7 *\[Pi]^2 * r*T^6)/(240*Tf)) - 
              ((8 \[Sqrt]2 *GF)/(3*mW^2))*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/
                  3)*2*((r*T^6*5.6822)/(\[Pi]^2 *Tf))) )^2)^(-1)*
      (1/(Exp[((r*T)/Tf) (g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3)] + 1)), {T, Ti, Tf},
     Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^10}, 
     MaxRecursion -> 100]]];

 a = f\[Nu]s[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, 1., 0.2]
b = f\[Nu]s[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, 0.2, 0.1]
c = f\[Nu]s[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, 1, 0.1]
a + b
c

(*Out[92]= 0.000918702

Out[93]= 0.00122894

Out[94]= 0.00127028

Out[95]= 0.00214764

Out[96]= 0.00127028*)
```

**Edit** : I tried dividing the integration region to several pieces and tried integrating separately and add it up. I suppose this might improve the result.

```
(*Edit*)
foo[r_?NumericQ, sin2\[Theta]_?NumericQ, ms_?NumericQ, Ti_?NumericQ, 
   Tf_?NumericQ, di_] := Total[Map[
    f\[Nu]s[r, sin2\[Theta], 
      ms, #[[1]], #[[2]]] &, {# + di, #} & /@ 
     Range[1 - di, 0.1, -di]]];

(*with di=0.01*)
foo[1, (2*10^-8)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, 1., .1, 0.01]

(*Out[284]= 0.00345849*)
```

Data files used for the integration are [gstar.txt](https://pastebin.com/RKa3r1Hz) and [rate.txt](https://pastebin.com/MnrE0GaS)

Answer (score 1):

The function you try to integrate is going to zero at $T>0.7$, it is why `NIntegrate` with option `Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^10}` produced substantial error. To solve this problem we first define function

```
dofdata = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "gstar.txt", "Table"]; 
g = Interpolation[dofdata, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Hermite"];
ratedata = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "rate.txt", "Table"];
Subscript[C, e] = 
  Interpolation[ratedata, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   Method -> "Hermite"];

f = Compile[{{r, _Real}, {sin2\[Theta], _Real}, {ms, _Real}, {T, 
_Real}, {Tf, _Real}}, 
     With[{GF = 1.166/10^5, MPl = 1.22*10^19, \[Eta]B = 6.05/10^10, 
    mZ = 91.1876, mW = 80.379}, 
       -((0.25*GF^2*(Sqrt[90/(8*Pi^3)]*MPl)*(r*T^6)*
        Subscript[C, e][
         T]*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3)*((T*Derivative[1][g][T])/(3*g[T]) + 1)*
               ((ms^2*sin2\[Theta])/((2*(r*T^2)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/
             Tf))^2)/(Tf*(T^3*
          Sqrt[g[T]])*(E^(((r*T)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/Tf) + 1)*
               ((1/
             4)*((GF^2*(r*T^6)*Subscript[C, e][T]*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/
              Tf)^2 + (ms^2/((2*(r*T^2)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/Tf) - 
                       (-((2*(8*Sqrt[2]*GF)*(5.6822*r*
                    T^6)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/((3*mW^2)*(Pi^2*
                    Tf))) - (2*(8*Sqrt[2]*GF)*(7*Pi^2*r*
                    T^6)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/
                            ((3*mZ^2)*(240*Tf)) + (2*
                  Sqrt[2]*1.20206*\[Eta]B*GF*T^3)/(4*
                  Pi^2)))^2 + ((ms^2*
               sin2\[Theta])/((2*(r*T^2)*(g[T]/g[Tf])^(1/3))/
               Tf))^2)))], 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

Plot `f`

```
Plot[f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, .1, 1}]
  Now we can integrate as usual and check sum
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
NIntegrate[ f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, .1, 1}]

(*Out[]= -0.00453549*)

 aa = NIntegrate[f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, .1, .2}]

(*Out[]= -0.000544113*)

 bb = NIntegrate[f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, .2, 1}]

(*Out[]= -0.00399137*)

 aa + bb

(*Out[]= -0.00453549*)
```

We can also integrate with reverse order. In this case we have messages, but final result is not differ from above (with sign counting)

```
in[6]:= c = NIntegrate[
 f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, 1, .1}]

During evaluation of In[6]:= CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 4 should be a machine-size real number.

Out[6]= 0.00453549

In[7]:= a = 
 NIntegrate[f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, .2, .1}]

During evaluation of In[7]:= CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 4 should be a machine-size real number.

Out[7]= 0.000544113

In[8]:= b = 
 NIntegrate[f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.], {x, 1, .2}]

Out[8]= 0.00399137

In[9]:= a + b

Out[9]= 0.00453549
```

Comment: I get the idea of taking T as a variable and integrating. There is a small difference from my problem and from the answer, Integration runs from `Ti=1` to `Tf=0.1`. In your answer it seems you took `Tf=1`. If you put `Tf=0.1`, the function I am trying to integrate goes to almost zero after 0.2. and the `aa`, `bb` will be positive. So when I run your code with `Tf=0.1`, I am getting `aa+bb = 0.00127028`, which was the same result I got with my code in question. Can you edit the answer with `Tf=0.1` and see what is `aa+bb`?

Comment: @annoying_noob Please, see update to my answer. Final result is the same as above ( with sign counting).

Comment: I meant the last argument in your function `f[1, (20.*10^-9)^(1/2), 2.*10^-6, x, 1.]`, that is supposed to be `Tf`? if you take it as `1.`, `g[Tf]=g[1]` in the expression of function. and it is not equal to `g[Tf]=g[0.1]`. I am trying to integrate the expression from $1 \text{GeV}$ to $0.1 \text{GeV}$. and it has the term `g[Tf]` which depends on final temperature. In your edit, last argument of `f` is `1`. Shouldn't that also change to `0.1`?. Also for a fact, this function peaks at QCD phase transition temperature, which is $T \approx 0.15 \text{GeV}$ which I am getting if `Tf=0.1` in `f`

Comment: @annoying_noob In your code `Tf ` is parameter. Then there is now reason to compare `a+ b` and `c` computed with different `Tf`.